# Splitting string in r and putting them in new columns in new data frame

Tags: r, split, character

I want to do this in R.
I run a code to extract paths of all folders and subfolders. I get the list mentioned below. I want to apply a set of rules to this:

1. If 1 `"/"` is encountered in the whole line then replace that "/" with `"/Folder/"`
2. If 2 `"/"` is encountered in the whole line then do nothing.
3. If 3 or MORE `"/"` are encountered then ignore the first and last "/" and replace all remaining "/" with `"-"`

The code I run is to extract file path is:

```
  b<-list.files(path="/Users/Mohit/Desktop/Company/Database",recursive=TRUE)

  [1] "Accounts/Academic History.pdf"                       "Accounts/Contract.pdf"                              
  [3] "Accounts/Credit/Analyst/Banking/TFileOutput.txt"     "Accounts/Credit/Analyst/untitled.jpg"               
  [5] "Accounts/Credit/background.jpg"                      "Accounts/Credit/background.xcf"                     
  [7] "Accounts/Debit/index.html"                           "Human Resources/RStudio-0.98.1073.dmg"              
  [9] "Information Technology/Iti.pdf"                      "Logistics/1610085_10152585224658626_398303669_n.jpg"
  [11] "Sales/947309_10152376144413626_1056138683_n.jpg"
```

Im not able to understand which function to use. stringr package with sapply maybe?
I want to put this in a column with a heading and export it as text file.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much

Comment: I apologise for the way my code has turned out. It should much better. There are 11 lines

Comment: I updated with the new info.  Check if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me so much. I was trying to use sapply which u didn't. Is there a reason as to why you didn't use sapply?

Comment: `sapply` and the `apply` family of functions are in some ways implicitly using the `loops`.  Here, `ifelse` is vectorized, so I used it instead of using `sapply`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps:

```
library(stringr)
Ct <- str_count(b, "/")
b1 <- ifelse(Ct==1, gsub("[/]", "/Folder/", b), 
        ifelse(Ct>=3, gsub("(^([^/]+[/])|([/][^/]+)$)(*SKIP)(*F)|[/]", "-",b,
                                         perl=TRUE), b))

 b1
 #[1] "Accounts/Folder/Academic History.pdf"                      
 #[2] "Accounts/Folder/Contract.pdf"                              
 #[3] "Accounts/Credit-Analyst-Banking/TFileOutput.txt"           
 #[4] "Accounts/Credit-Analyst/untitled.jpg"                      
 #[5] "Accounts/Credit/background.jpg"                            
 #[6] "Accounts/Credit/background.xcf"                            
 #[7] "Accounts/Debit/index.html"                                 
 #[8] "Human Resources/Folder/RStudio-0.98.1073.dmg"              
 #[9] "Information Technology/Folder/Iti.pdf"                     
 #[10] "Logistics/Folder/1610085_10152585224658626_398303669_n.jpg"
 #[11] "Sales/Folder/947309_10152376144413626_1056138683_n.jpg"
```

If you want to create a `data.frame` and then export as `.txt` file

```
   dat <- data.frame(b, b1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
   write.table(dat, file="Mohit.txt", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, sep=",")
```

#### Update

If you need to create 3 columns based on `b1`

```
  datN <- setNames(read.table(text=b1, sep="/"), c("Class", "Title", "File"))
  head(datN,2)
  #     Class  Title                 File
  #1 Accounts Folder Academic History.pdf
  #2 Accounts Folder         Contract.pdf
```

Now, you can save the file using `write.table`

#### data

```
 b <- c("Accounts/Academic History.pdf", "Accounts/Contract.pdf", "Accounts/Credit/Analyst/Banking/TFileOutput.txt", 
 "Accounts/Credit/Analyst/untitled.jpg", "Accounts/Credit/background.jpg", 
 "Accounts/Credit/background.xcf", "Accounts/Debit/index.html", 
 "Human Resources/RStudio-0.98.1073.dmg", "Information Technology/Iti.pdf", 
 "Logistics/1610085_10152585224658626_398303669_n.jpg","Sales/947309_10152376144413626_1056138683_n.jpg"
```

Comment: You may want to add showing how to add b1 as a column and then export to a text file.

Comment: @user2923027 No problem.  Have a great weekend to you as well!

Comment: I want to now split this into 3 columns based on "/" - Class, Title & File and export this into a text file. I will use str_split(b1,"/"). Is that right?

Comment: You may want to start a new question, provide the code so far, and clarify what you want as output.

Comment: My bad. I am really sorry. In my first question I would like to replace "/" with "/Folder/" I forgot to mention the last slash to you although I corrected mine. Now all the rows will have 3 "/"

Comment: thanks sir. I will now try to split the lines into 3 columns .Split when "/" is encountered.